# Draw points using sharpgl

Tags: c#

I am trying to draw points using sharpgl but when the code is compiled it gives only white console with no output why is this happening and what is the solution of this?

```
private static int width = 400, height = 300;
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Glut.glutInit();
    Glut.glutInitDisplayMode(Glut.GLUT_SINGLE | Glut.GLUT_RGB);
    Glut.glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    Glut.glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Tutorial");
    init();
    Glut.glutDisplayFunc(OnDisplay);
    Glut.glutMainLoop();
}

private static void OnDisplay()
{
    Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | Gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gl.glLoadIdentity();
    Gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);
    Gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    Gl.glPointSize(10.0f);
    Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_POINTS);
    Gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    Gl.glEnd();
}
static void init()
{

    Gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aim your camera the right way with `gluLookAt()`.

See [this tutorial for more info](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/keyboard-example-moving-around-the-world/).